# Network Packet Payload Error when Trying to Create Distributed Availability Group

Tags: availability-groups, distributed-availability-groups

I am attempting to create a distributed AG on SQL 2016 SP1, but keep getting the following errors.  I have tried this in a VirtualBox (local desktop) and actual VMWare virtual environment but getting the same errors each time.

The AGs creates successfully on both WFCs, but when I try to "ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [Dist AG Name] JOIN" on the primary replica of the 'remote' AG, the command completes successfully, but I immediately get this error in the log:

> A connection timeout has occurred while attempting to establish a
>   connection to availability replica 'AG1' with id
>   [FCAA4083-D6B8-1BAC-9E8C-6AECE34513E6]. Either a networking or
>   firewall issue exists, or the endpoint address provided for the
>   replica is not the database mirroring endpoint of the host server
>   instance.

On the primary replica of the 'local' AG, I start getting these errors in the log repeatedly:

> Length specified in network packet payload did not match number of
>   bytes read; the connection has been closed. Please contact the vendor
>   of the client library. [CLIENT: 192.168.56.104]

These are the bytes that show up in Event Viewer event:

```
0000: AC 45 00 00 14 00 00 00   ¬E...... 
0008: 14 00 00 00 41 00 47 00   ....A.G. 
0010: 31 00 53 00 45 00 52 00   1.S.E.R.
0018: 56 00 45 00 52 00 31 00   V.E.R.1.
0020: 5C 00 41 00 47 00 31 00   \.A.G.1.
0028: 49 00 4E 00 53 00 54 00   I.N.S.T.
0030: 31 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   1.......
```

In both environments, I am only dealing with a single subnet and a single domain.  I've also tried removing all special characters from VM hostnames, instance names, AG names, and listener names during troubleshooting.

Wondering if anyone has ran into this before.  I don't see anything in the SP2 release notes that suggests its a bug, but I'm willing to try an SP2 upgrade if anyone thinks its worthwhile. (Unfortunately I am not in a position to be able to upgrade my prod environment for some time which is why I haven't tried it yet.)

I can also post full endpoint/AG/listener creation scripts if anyone is willing to try to reproduce or provide troubleshooting tips.

Thanks!

Comment: So update... I updated all involved instances to SP2 CU6 in both environments and still getting the same errors.  I've even setup a parallel VirtualBox environment on a separate workstation with freshly downloaded binaries and getting the same errors.  So, I can only assume that I am doing something completely wrong (not likely) or there is some bug in SP1-up that hasn't hit the forums yet.  If anyone can attempt to reproduce it would be fantastic.  It will be a few days before I have access to open a support case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I finally found the problem and it was my own dumb mistake.  When you create the distributed availability group, for the LISTENER_URL clauses, you have to specify the listener DNS names, **but the mirroring endpoint ports**.  I was specifying the listener DNS names and the listener ports.

For example, here is my endpoint definition (note port 5022):

```
CREATE ENDPOINT [Hadr_endpoint] 
    STATE=STARTED
    AS TCP (LISTENER_PORT = 5022, LISTENER_IP = (192.168.159.102))
    FOR DATA_MIRRORING (ROLE = ALL, AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS NEGOTIATE
, ENCRYPTION = REQUIRED ALGORITHM AES)
GO
```

Here is my listener definition (note port 1435):

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [AG1]
ADD LISTENER N'AG1LISTENER' (
WITH IP
((N'192.168.232.203', N'255.255.255.0')
)
, PORT=1435);
GO
```

And here is the CORRECT way to define the distributed AG (note listener DNS name but endpoint port):

```
CREATE AVAILABILITY GROUP [DistAG]
WITH (DISTRIBUTED)
AVAILABILITY GROUP ON
    'AG1' WITH
    (
    LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://AG1LISTENER:5022',    
    AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   
    FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   
    SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC
    ),
    'AG2' WITH
    (
    LISTENER_URL = 'tcp://AG2LISTENER:5022',    
    AVAILABILITY_MODE = ASYNCHRONOUS_COMMIT,   
    FAILOVER_MODE = MANUAL,   
    SEEDING_MODE = AUTOMATIC
    );
GO
```

This is explained very clearly in the huge purple note highlighted in this article that I somehow completely overlooked before:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-distributed-availability-groups?view=sql-server-2017